# Getting `Error: Can't resolve 'fs'` While Adding Google Maps API to Gatsby Project

Tags: google-maps, gatsby

> TL;DR - Getting the `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[MY-PATH]/node_modules/dotenv/lib'` while trying to implement the Google Maps API in my Gatsby project.

Hello,

I'm working on a Yelp Clone in Gatsby as a personal project to add to my portfolio. Right now I'm having some issues bringing a "vanilla" implementation of the Google Maps API into my map component.

Here's how I have the app's `Map` component set up so far:

#### map.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env`
});

const MAPS_API_KEY = process.env.MAPS_API_KEY;

const Map = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.initMap = initMap;
    runScript(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${MAPS_API_KEY}&callback=initMap`
    );
  });

  const initMap = () => {
    // Declare map object
    new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: { lat: 39.952583, lng: -75.165222 },
      zoom: 14
    });
  };

  return <div id="map" />;
};

export default Map;

function runScript(src) {
  const body = window.document.querySelector("body");
  const script = window.document.createElement("script");

  script.src = src;
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;
  body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", script);

  script.onerror = () => {
    throw new Error("Failed to load Google Maps");
  };
}
```

In summary, the bottom function, `runScript` takes the Map's URL and adds a `<script>` tag to the `window.document` object before the closing `<body>` tag.

Based on another project I've worked on where the call to initialize the map is set up inside `componentDidMount`, I've set up the `runScript` function to be called inside of `Map`'s call to the `useEffect` hook which first acts to initialize the map (`initMap`).

The error I'm running into when re-building the app, however, indicates there's something wrong with a `'fs'` value which appears to be tied to my use of the dotenv library:

#### Console error

```
Error: ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '[MY-PATH]/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
  resolve 'fs' in '[MY-PATH]/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
```

My .env file contents

```
YELP_API_KEY=[API-VALUE]
MAPS_API_KEY=[API-VALUE]
```

Up to this point, [research into this error](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/233) has led me to [various articles](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5) on the web which imply I should be making a change to Gatsby's webpack configuration so my environment variables are accepted. Since [setting up a custom webpack config](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/) apparently requires a few steps to programmatically alter the project's webpack file and the example provided on this topic in Gatsby's docs isn't readily transferable to my own issue, I've been looking at other possibilities for resolving the problem but remain stumped.

Any help or tip to help move me in the right direction would obviously be greatly appreciated.

In the meantime, I'll be reading through the Webpack docs.

Thanks.

#### Environment and configuration settings:

- Some of the below files are ***likely not*** relevant to the present problem, however, Gatsby encourages you include the following details when reporting an issue, so:

#### Project Env Versions

- Gatsby version: 2.1.4
- Node.js version: 10.15.0
- OS version: 10.14.4

#### gatsby-config.js

```js
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env`
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Yelp Clone App`,
    description: `A simple clone of Yelp for  viewing Mexican restaurants in the Philadlephia area`,
    author: `Jamie Strausbaugh`
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-yelp`
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `phillyMex`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

#### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.1.4",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.29",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.17",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.20",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.29",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^2.1.11",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.13",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.app/unit-testing\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
```

#### gatsby-node.js

```js
const path = require(`path`);

exports.createPages = async function({ actions, graphql }) {
  // Query for restaurant nodes to use in creating pages
  return await graphql(`
    {
      allYelpBusiness {
        edges {
          node {
            alias
            name
            image_url
            url
            review_count
            categories {
              title
            }
            rating
            coordinates {
              latitude
              longitude
            }
            price
            location {
              display_address
            }
            display_phone
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    // Create pages for each restaurant
    result.data.allYelpBusiness.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      actions.createPage({
        // Path for this page is required
        path: node.alias,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/venueDetails.js`),
        context: {
          // Data passed to context is available
          // in page queries as GraphQL variables
          alias: node.alias
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: hi Jamie, dotenv is for server-side usage only, it looks like that code is being run in the browser. IIRC, for browser side stuff you can append `GATSBY_` in front of your variable in `.env` and it will be loaded automatically (browser side only).

Comment: Hi Derek,
Thank you so much for taking the time to read into my error. I was a little suspicious about including the `require` method at the top of my file for accessing my env variable - with my limited experience working so far with node, I've only seen `require` used in server-side code before this. Somewhere along the line, I got it into my head this would work at the top of my client-side React file.

Comment: Your answer put me back on the right track, however, the steps needed to resolve the error in my case were just a bit different, in that I'm accessing env variables in the project scope rather than the OS-level which is where the `GATSBY_` prefix may be utilized.  Still, the answer to my question was right there on the [same page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) of the Gatsby docs. 

Very glad I don't have to programmatically set up a custom Webpack config, at least not yet.

Onward! Thanks again 

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem! Would you post an answer with your implementation? Using google map with gatsby is probably a common use case, I think it'll be helpful for others. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

While it didn't resolve the issue for me, a lot of people who get this error have had luck with [this solution](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17557#issuecomment-531518940):

> - Remove `package-lock.json` and/or `yarn.lock`
> - Issue `gatsby clean` to purge any stale data.
> - Remove `node_modules` folder.
> - Install the dependencies again with your package manager of choice, either npm or yarn.
> - Issue `gatsby develop` and see if the error does not pop back.